# Spring: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I ceaselessly met problem mentioned in the question title. 
I would like to introduce some `DI` using i.a. `applicationContext.xml` file and `@ImportResource` annotation. I have checked some ways of passing `applicationContext.xml` location to `@ImportResource`
but they do not work. Compilation is performed with tests turned off. I am posting below parts of some files in the project and project tree. Do you have any ideas how can I overcome the problem?

**GitHubDetailsApplication**

```
package pl.cd.githubdetails;

// imports ...

@SpringBootApplication
// doesnt work:
// @ImportResource(locations = {"applicationContext.xml"})
// @ImportResource(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
// @ImportResource({"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})
@ImportResource({"/applicationContext.xml"}) // also doesnt work
public class GitHubDetailsApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GitHubDetailsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Project tree**

[image: project tree]

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="pl.cd.githubdetails"/>

</beans>
```

**GitController**

```
package pl.cd.githubdetails;

// imports 

@RestController
public class GitController {

    @Autowired
    GitHttpClient gitHttpClient;
// ...
}
```

**GitHttpClient**

```
package pl.cd.githubdetails;


public class GitHttpClient {
    // imports ...
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public GitHttpClient() {
        this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    }
    // ...
}
```

**EDIT** I insert stack.

```
2019-09-19 00:25:20.413  WARN 13584 --- [main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'gitController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'gitHttpClient'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'pl.cd.githubdetails.GitHttpClient' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2019-09-19 00:25:20.415  INFO 13584 --- [main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-09-19 00:25:20.425  INFO 13584 --- [main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-09-19 00:25:20.497 ERROR 13584 --- [main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field gitHttpClient in pl.cd.githubdetails.GitController required a bean of type 'pl.cd.githubdetails.GitHttpClient' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'pl.cd.githubdetails.GitHttpClient' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Show us what exception exactly you get.

Comment: @mentallurg question edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller expects that there is a bean of type `GitHttpClient` that will be injected:

```
@Autowired
GitHttpClient gitHttpClient;
```

But there is no such bean. Why? Because you have not annotated your class `GitHttpClient` as a Spring bean. What can you do? Annotate it as a `Service` or as a `Component`:

```
@Service
public class GitHttpClient {
    ...
}
```